# Skype Notifications Not Working After StartUp

Tags: windows-10, notifications, autostart, skype-for-windows-10

I'm using the Windows 10 Skype App and enabled autostart. However, I do not receive any notifications for Skype, as long as I don't manually start/open it for the first time myself.

I tried to add the Skype app additionally to `shell:startup` but I don't know how/if I can do that.

Comment: Uninstall Skype (Windows Apps), restart and install it again. Works fine here.

Comment: In Skype *Settings > General*, is "Automatically start Skype" enabled?

Comment: @harrymc - Yes, it's enabled...

Comment: @John OK, why not, I can try that